# Converting code that uses fopen to curl because host is blocking fopen

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, fopen

I'm working on Wordpress and I know literally nothing about `PHP`. I'm trying to get a scroller with post excerpts to work but it uses `fopen()` but it is turned off on my customers' host.

```
$f = fopen( $url, 'r' );

while( $data = fread( $f, 4096 ) ) { $xml .= $data; }

fclose( $f );
```

Can this simply be written into curl?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast respsonse. I'm closer I must still be missing something I guess.

Comment: are you sure that your server supports Curl?

Comment: Pretty sure. I am receiving no errors it just isn't pulling the content.